# Performing kmeans on a train set of images and sift descriptors

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, scipy, k-means, sift

I'm trying to create a codebook to be used for  CBIR task. Everything works until I try to perform kmeans, then I have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path", line 36, in <module>
scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(descriptors, k_or_guess=500, iter=20, thresh=1e-05)
File "path", line 513, in kmeans
No = obs.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

If instead of the scipy function for kmeans I use

```
cv2.kmeans(descriptors, K=500, criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 1, 10), attempts=1, flags=cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

I have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path", line 35, in <module>
cv2.kmeans(descriptors, K=500, criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 1,  10), attempts=1, flags=cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
TypeError: data is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

My code so far is:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import *
import numpy as np
import glob
import cv2


#CB

#creating a list of images 
images = []
for infile in glob.glob('path'):
    pic = cv2.imread(infile)
    images.append(pic)

np.random.shuffle(images)
my_set = images

#split set
train = my_set[:120]
test = my_set[120:]

#get train descriptors
descriptors = [cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(pic, None) for pic in train]


#kmeans
scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(desc, k_or_guess=1000, iter=20, thresh=1e-05)

#then indexing 
#then implement retrieval
```

It seems that the problem is with the object "descriptors" which is a list of lists. I've tried to transform it to a np.array, but that approach wasn't working as well.
What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Have u tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885751/cv2-kmeans-usage-in-python

Comment: Why are you using SciPy's kmeans instead of sklearn's? Just curious.

Comment: @MisterJT apologies for this late reply. It was an assignment, if I remember correctly we were introduced to that library and were supposed to use it to solve our task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, apparently the problem is solved by changing a little bit the code and instead of the list comprehension I did:

```
descriptors = np.array([])
for pic in train:
    kp, des = cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(pic, None)
    descriptors = np.append(descriptors, des)

desc = np.reshape(descriptors, (len(descriptors)/128, 128))
desc = np.float32(desc)
```

which works with the cv2 kmeans function.

Answer (score 0):

for python 3 it should be:

```
descriptors = np.array([])
for pic in train:
    kp, des = cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(pic, None)
    descriptors = np.append(descriptors, des)

desc = np.reshape(descriptors, (len(descriptors)//128, 128)) # (notice the // here)
desc = np.float32(desc)
```